# Opera deselecting despite e.preventDefault on mousedown

Tags: javascript, events, preventdefault, rte

I'm creating a very simple RTE from scratch designed to work with only new browsers.

Everything works fine, except in Opera i cannot get it to stop deselecting text when pressing the toolbar. I created a simple page to test if this was part of my little program or if it always occurs, and it does.

For example i create a page with some code, this works fine in all big browsers except Opera:

```
<p id="tmp">This text cannot be selected</p>
<p id="lispsum">Lorem ips...im id est laborum.</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
var el = document.getElementById('tmp');
el.addEventListener('mousedown', function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
}, false);
</script>
```

In browsers such as Chrome and Firefox, selecting some text in the "lipsum" paragraph and then clicking in the "tmp" paragraph retains the selection. In Opera (tested in version 12) it deselects it. If mouse is held down, the selection gets deselected only if it the cursor is not moved. So in Opera there is a difference in behaviour between "non-drag" (ie a long click) and a "click and drag".

I have tried with the evt.stopPropagation() method, evt.returnValue = false; and return false; added to the handler like this:

```
el.addEventListener('mousedown', function(evt) {
    if(evt.stopPropagation) evt.stopPropagation();
    if(evt.preventDefault) evt.preventDefault();
    if(evt.returnValue) evt.returnValue = false;
    return false;
}, false);
```

I then added identical handlers for the following events: mouseup, mousedown, mouseout, click, select, selectstart and selectchange. Nothing helped.

I also tried using the jQuery method "disableSelection()":

```
$("#tmp").disableSelection();
```

but the behaviour was the same, the text in the element is not selectable, but clicking within it still deselects any previouis selections.

Anyone else encounter this problem? Very frustrating.

EDIT: Reading my comment again and do some testing i can conclude there must be a fault in the "click" event because of the difference between long click and a click and drag. The mouseup event is fired in both cases, but the click is only fired if the cursor is not moved (which is when the text gets deslected).

Comment: `return false` as the last statement in your handler?

Comment: Also, `evt.returnValue = false` but that's IE related I think.

Comment: i added both `evt.returnValue = false;` and `return false;` with no effect...

Comment: Did you try to also stop `mouseup` and maybe `click` events?

Comment: Are there any JS errors in Opera? A good practice is to `if(evt.preventDefault) evt preventDefault()`, etc. `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation` are browser dependent. Not sure about them in Opeara, but if the lack of one of them causes an error, that might prevent further correct execution of your script.

Comment: yeah... i've done that too....

Comment: Either use or inspire from the magnificence that is [jQuery UI => disableSelection()](http://api.jqueryui.com/disableSelection/)

Comment: @Khez the jquery ui function doesnt work either, it creates the same effect. Selection is disabled on the element, but it still deselects any other selection.